# Buscar un objeto en una List donde 2 objetos iguales no tienen la misma instancia

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, combobox

Estoy queriendo rellenar un comboBox con una serie de Materias pero no quiero que se repitan.
Lo que hago es recorrer cursos ya filtrados para el alumno que contienen un id de materia.

```
listaCursos = curlog.GetAllFiltrados();
        foreach (Curso c in listaCursos)
        {
            Materia = matlog.GetOne(c.IDMateria);
            if (idPlan == Materia.IdPlan)
            {
                if (!materiasFiltradas.Contains(Materia))//ACA ESTA EL PROBLEMA
                {
                    materiasFiltradas.Add(Materia);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Traigo la Materia, me fijo si son del plan del alumno y la agrego a una lista.
El problema aparece cuando quiero ver si la materia ya está en la lista, porque el método Contains trabaja con la referencia a la instancia del objeto y no por el contenido, entonces por más que la materia sea la misma no lo toma como igual. Como puedo hacer para que no me agregue 2 veces la misma materia? Gracias!

Comment: puedes hacer una búsqueda en la lista con `Linq` quedaría algo como esto:  `if(!materiasFiltradas.Any(x => x.IDMateria == Materia.IDMateria))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas `Linq` puedes realizar una búsqueda usando `Any()`, la función lo que hace es buscar los elementos que cumplan con cierta condición y si hay al menos 1 elemento te devolverá un `true` sino `false` con el que puedes trabajar tus condicionales.

Quedaría así lo que quieres:

```
    listaCursos = curlog.GetAllFiltrados();
    foreach (Curso c in listaCursos)
    {
        Materia = matlog.GetOne(c.IDMateria);
        if (idPlan == Materia.IdPlan)
        {
            if(!materiasFiltradas.Any(x => x.IDMateria == Materia.IDMateria))
            {
                materiasFiltradas.Add(Materia);
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó a la perfección, también agregué la parte que comentó @ctm002 Materia != null para que no me tire error si trae algún nulo.

Comment: Listo, que bueno que te haya funcionado amigo éxitos con tus proyectos.

Comment: Se puede reducir aun mas, y dejar algo totalmente funcional y declarativo : listaCursos.Select(c => matlog.GetOne(c.IDMateria)).Where(materia => materia!= null && materia.IdPlan == idPlan).ToList().ForEach(Materia => { if (!materiasFiltradad.Any(x => x.IDMateria == Materia.IDMateria)) materiasFiltradas.Add(Materia);});